# How should I partition a 250 GB SSD for my laptop?

Tags: partition, disk, ssd

I'm replacing my laptop's HDD with a 250 GB SSD.

Right now, the laptop has just one partition mounted on `/` (on a 228 GB HDD). I could just do the exact same thing, but on desktops I'm used to do finer partitioning: At least a separate `/boot` and a separate `/home` for personal non-system files (and a swap partition, but I guess we don't want that on an SSD, right?)

Some information about this system:

- The new SSD capacity is 250 GB.
- One single regular user (myself).
- Extremely rare use by a "guest" user, so we can ignore that.
- Lenovo X201, Intel M540 @ 2.5 GHz, 8 GB memory
- Used for screening video (over VGA, woe is me), typically at 1920x1080. Quite a lot of writing of video files.
- Other uses: Editing and viewing documents, browsing the web, reading email, a bit of coding.
- Current disk usage not including video files - under 40 GB

So I'd like an overall suggested partitioning scheme, or more specific "do X but don't do Y when partitioning" advice. For the benefit of other readers, please indicate when you're using information about my specific system and when your recommendations are general.

**Notes:**

- I know that partitioning an SSD (these days) does not cause extra wear as the hardware does wear leveling across partition; I just want to know if I should make any different considerations when partitioning an SSD rather than an HDD.
- Other readers may also be interested in [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds) (on AskUbuntu.com) regarding what to do *after* partitioning when switching to an SSD.

Comment: This is absolutely on topic here, and welcome to stay, but you might want to check out [su] instead. This is a general question about SSDs and the (I believe now wrong and outdated) idea that you don't want too many partitions on them to minimise wear. My very limited understanding is that this is no longer the case with modern SSD and you should partition as you would on any other system. But SU is the best place for such broader hardware questions. Also, see: [Disadvantages of partitioning an SSD?](//superuser.com/a/1081730)

Comment: @terdon: I actually did not mean to suggest I want less partitions necessarily. After all, on the HDD I only have one partition... I was just asking if there should be any difference in how I choose partition an HDD vs an SSD.

Comment: @terdon: So, on topic, but no answers.